# HTML5 Validaiton Error cut off on Android Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, android, css, html, google-chrome

I am facing an issue where some instances of Mobile Chrome (Does not occur on Gaalxy Tab3 but was seen on a Nexus 7, Nexus 5, and Galaxy Nexus S2) will display error messages, and the container of the error message will cut through the HTML5 validation error message. This occurs on both orientations. Is there anything I can do to influence this behavior, or is this a bug within Chrome itself? If so, where can I log it at?

[image: Image of a form being validated with HTML5. The bubble the error message pops up in is cutting through the error message itself]

Comment: Can you provide me with the code

Comment: There is no code, this is the HTML5 validation error messages.